# Change scope of tax catalog price calculation to store view

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, multistore, tax, tax-calculation

I need to change the Catalog Prices Tax Calculation Settings scope to `store view` rather than `website` but I've not found a solution as of yet. Is there any way to do this?

The current set up is as follows:
Websites for UK, US & EU
Stores for Retail and Trade for each of the above.

Retail store prices are input inclusive of tax whereas trade store prices are input exclusive of tax.

If it's not possible to change the scope of this calculation, does anyone have an alternative method?

I forgot to add that I'm using Magento 2.3.3

Thank you.